# Why is this set $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\xi$?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set, borel-sets

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal C}$

Let $\C$ denote the Cantor space and let $U\subseteq \C\times\C$ be $\C$-universal for $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi(\C)$, for some $1\leq\xi<\omega_1$, meaning that $U\in\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi(\C\times \C)$ and $\Sigma^0_\xi(\C)=\{U_y\mid y\in \C\}$, where for $y\in\C$, $U_y=\{x\in\C\mid (y,x)\in U\}$.

Let $A=\{y\in\C\mid (y,y)\not\in U\}$. Why is $A\in\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\xi(\C)$? I see that $A$ cannot be in $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi(\C)$, but it's not clear to me why it must be in the complementary class. This is a step in a proof in Kechris's book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is the following closure property of the Borel classes (and well-behaved pointclasses in general):

> Each Borel class is closed under continuous preimages.

More precisely, given Polish spaces $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ and a continuous map $f:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$, taking $f$-preimages does not increase topological complexity: if $X\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ is in ${\bf\Sigma^0_\xi}(\mathcal{B})$ then $f^{-1}(X)$ is in ${\bf\Sigma^0_\xi}(\mathcal{A})$.

This is a good exercise; the key point is to think about how taking preimages interacts with intersections, unions, and complements. Note that *images* are much more poorly behaved than preimages in this sense (and this leads to the difference between Borel and analytic sets).

---

In this case the continuous map we're interested in is the **diagonal embedding** $$d:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}: c\mapsto (c,c).$$ This is indeed a continuous map from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$, so we can apply the closure result above. In particular we have $d^{-1}(U)\in{\bf\Sigma^0_\xi}(\mathcal{C})$. Now consider $\mathcal{C}\setminus d^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Ah, of course, I hadn't realized that preimages fact, but it's clear in hindsight, thanks!